# Retain the option in the dropdown list in php

Tags: php

I have a dropdown with the following options:

i.)All

ii.)Public User
Where The option public user is selected from the database

```
<select name="desc" id="selectbox">
    <?php 
    echo '<option  value="all" >All</option>';

    $a=$obj->getPublicUser();
     echo '<option  value="PublicUser" >'.$a.'</option>';

    ?>
    </select>
```

$a has getPublicUser() :

```
 public function getPublicUser() 
     {


        $publicuser=self::PUBLIC_USER;
       $result= mysql_query(" select category_desc from user_category where category_id=4");
       if($result)
       {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
          {
              $user=$row['category_desc'];
          }
       }
       return $user;
 }
```

I have used 
My Submit button is as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="Get Report" />
```

My problem is On selecting option ALL and clicking on submit button the all option is retained. But on selecting Public user and then clicking on submit button the option resets to "all". How can I make the public user retain even after the submit ? Plz help

Comment: What $_GET['desc'] returns?

Comment: sorry thats the other part of the code...that works fine,i have problem with this one..i have edited it

Comment: Not getting your query exactly.

Comment: Can you put your array $a here? And also "when i press public user it resets back to all", this is not understandable.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i hv included my function. and what i meant is when i press public user option it doesnt stay after displaying the table it shows "all" option.i want it to stay in public user only

Comment: I have tried to explain my problem elaborately.hope you understand. jus have a look

Comment: @jermina, it's simple just show your array $a. Then only we can give you solution.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i have a category table "user_category" in wich category_id '4' is public user so $a returns  public user.

Comment: @jermina please up-vote the answer also, now you have that much point that you can up-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this, Hope it help you:-

```
<html>
<form name = "client_question">
<select name="desc" id="selectbox">
    <?php 
    echo '<option  value="All" >All</option>';
    echo '<option  value="PublicUser">PublicUser</option>';
    echo '<option  value="NormalUser">NormalUser</option>';
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="Get Report" />
</form>
<script>
<?php if(isset($_GET['desc']) && $_GET['desc']) {?>
    document.getElementById("selectbox").value = "<?php echo $_GET['desc'] ?>";
<?php } ?>
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this

```
if (isset($_GET['desc']) && $_GET['desc'] == "PublicUser") selected="seleceted"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.